# Comparing two registered values in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that putting together to patch all my  Pi docker hosts.

The Steps should be

1. Update apt cache
2. Get running containers
3. Display hostname and running containers value
4. Stop containers
5. Update packages
6. Reboot
7. Get running containers
8. Display hostname and running containers value
9. Compare step 3 to 8 and fail if they don't match

Step 9 is the one I am struggling with.

`main.yml`

```
---
- name: Patching Raspberry pi
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
#  vars_files:
#    ./vars/vars.yml

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Update Apt Cache
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: true
        cache_valid_time: 3600

    - name: Get running containers
      community.docker.docker_host_info:
        containers: true
      register: docker_info

    - name: Show Number of running containers
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Hostname - {{ docker_info.host_info.Name }} has {{ docker_info.host_info.ContainersRunning }} Containers running"
      register: docker_pre_reboot

    - name: Stop running containers
      community.docker.docker_container:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: stopped
      loop: "{{ docker_info.containers | map(attribute='Id') | list }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Update all packages
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: "*"
        state: latest

    - name: Reboot
      ansible.builtin.reboot:

    - name: Get running containers
      community.docker.docker_host_info:
        containers: true
      register: docker_info

#    - name: Check Containers are running after reboot
#      ansible.builtin.debug:
#        msg: "Hostname - {{ docker_info.host_info.Name }} has {{ docker_info.host_info.ContainersRunning }} Containers running"
#      failed_when: docker_info.host_info.ContainersRunning != docker_pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning "

    - name: Compare Pre - Post Containers
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Pre-reboot Containers {{ docker_pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning }} - Post-reboot Containers {{ docker_info.host_info.ContainersRunning }}"
      failed_when: docker_info.host_info.ContainersRunning != docker_pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning
```

EDITED last task.

UPDATE: The last task always fails even when the output from the msg is

```
TASK [Compare values] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [pi-dev]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Pre-reboot Containers 5 - Post-reboot Containers 5"
}
```

Comment: In what way are you struggling? Are you getting errors? Unexpected behavior? Something else?

Comment: I have tweaked the last task to show the pre-reboot containers and post -reboot containers and the failed_when comparison is always failing even if the output from the message shows the same value

Answer (score 1):

After some messing around with the playbook, it seems the registered value from the ansible debug isnt the same as the value that comes from the docker_host_info.

so my new playbook is:

```
---
- name: Patching Raspberry pi
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
#  vars_files:
#    ./vars/vars.yml

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Update Apt Cache
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: true
        cache_valid_time: 3600

    - name: Get running containers
      community.docker.docker_host_info:
        containers: true
      register: pre_reboot

    - name: Show Number of running containers
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Hostname - {{ pre_reboot.host_info.Name }} has {{ pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning }} Containers running"

    - name: Stop running containers
      community.docker.docker_container:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: stopped
      loop: "{{ pre_reboot.containers | map(attribute='Id') | list }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Update all packages
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: "*"
        state: latest

    - name: Reboot 
      ansible.builtin.reboot:

    - name: Get running containers
      community.docker.docker_host_info:
        containers: true
      register: post_reboot

    - name: Compare Pre - Post Containers
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Pre-reboot Containers {{ pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning }} - Post-reboot Containers {{ post_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning }}"
      failed_when: pre_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning != post_reboot.host_info.ContainersRunning
```

and compares the pre and post values fine

Comment: Two suggestions here, 1. You have changed the couple of variables and that is not mentioned. To understand we need to use diff (think in beginners perspective) both code lines. 2. Better to avoid the code lines that doesn't make any sense which are in comments and just increases the code lines .